# Logstash: paser Field Content to Filter

Tags: logstash

I try to parse the log.

if the log "didn't" have 'specific' like as follow `logstash` prints ,then will be drop the event This is what `logstash` prints:

```
{
  "message" => "...",
   "host" => "10.10.10.20",
   "@version" => "1",
   "@timestamp" => "2016-04-12T02:28:18.233Z",
   "type" => "snmptrap",
    "1_3_6_1_2_1_1_3_0" => "21 days, 17:08:57.94",
   "1_3_6_1_6_3_1_1_4_1_0" => "specific::userdefined", 
 }
```

I can only specify the content of the field (prefix is specific) rather than its field name (1_3_6_1_6_3_1_1_4_1_0)

so how to parser the log to filter and to drop the event? What do I need to do?

If anyone knows how to do with it , please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your logs and grok patterns?

Comment: my log as described above .

Comment: This is your third copy of this issue, which isn't helping at all.

Comment: So you want to remove the event based on the value of the field, e.g. "specific::userdefined"?

Comment: that's right ! but it's based on the prefix "specific"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a filter such as:

```
filter{
    if "specific" in [1_3_6_1_6_3_1_1_4_1_0] {
        drop{}
    }
}
```

You can change 'in' to 'not in' if you would like the message dropped based on the absence of 'specific.'

You can also use a regex match if you need to match 'specific' at the beginning of the field:

```
if [1_3_6_1_6_3_1_1_4_1_0] =~ /^specific.+/ { drop{} }
```

To change this to not match 'specific' use the !~ operator in place of =~